# Reassigning unique_ptr of int

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a trivial example and I wouldn't ordinarily store an `int` on the heap, but I'm trying to understand how this works.

I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work:

```
  auto l = std::make_unique<int>;
  *l=8;
  std::cout << *l << std::endl;
```

I get:

> std::__1::default_delete > ()'   is not assignable

The compiler shows this error on the line `*l=8;`

I understand that `unique_ptr` is not itself reassignable, but that is not what I'm doing. I'm simply changing the value of what the pointer points to. With a regular pointer I'd do:

```
  int*h=new int;
  *h=7;
  std::cout << *h << std::endl;
```

I'm trying to emulate this behavior with the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Check C++ reference: [std::make_unique()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::make_unique<int>` is a function, you have to call it:

```
auto l = std::make_unique<int>();
```

Comment: thanks; interesting that the compiler didn't highlight this line when it reported the error, but rather highlighted the line `*l=8;`

Comment: @johnbakers That's because it's valid to assign a function pointer to a variable, it's just not valid to assign an `int` to a function.

Comment: @johnbakers Because you used auto. `l` is probably a function pointer now. And when you tried to dereference it and assign an int to it, the compiler saw a problem.

Comment: You defined `l` as an auto. So the compiler was quite happy to assume you meant that `l` was a function pointer to `std::make_unique<int>` and it is only when you tried to assign a new value to that function pointer that your mistake was apparent.

Comment: (nice example of why using `auto` can make it harder to locate coding errors)